# How to declare byte in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var timestamp = new Uint32Array[16];
 var timestamp2 = new byte[0];
```

that is my code but it doesnt work. Anyone can you help me please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare an array of byte in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025414/how-to-declare-an-array-of-byte-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first off: If you don't do some webgl stuff and would just like to store your timestamp just stick to an old fashioned Array.**

using ArrayBuffers and typed Arrays you **can** declare "byte-buffers" and create C like structs.

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16) // create a 16-byte buffer
```

to work with that buffer you have to create views

```
var int32View = new Int32Array(buffer)
```

after that you can access the buffer as you would access a normal array

```
for(var i = 0; i < int32View.length; i++){
  int32View[i]=i
}
```

more information about ArrayBuffers and typed arrays can be found here

[working with complex data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays#Working_with_complex_data_structures)

[ArrayBufferView - Typed array subclasses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView)

Comment: I get `'ArrayBuffer' is undefined` when I try this in IE9.

Comment: i think ArrayBuffer isn't available in IE9 but it's available in IE 10.

Comment: Ok, then we just have to wait a decade or so until noone uses IE9 any more... ;)

Comment: scrap ie ;) and let's hope microsoft will stop that 1000 different versions madness!

Answer (score 2):

may be you can try
var timestamp2 = new Uint8Array();

Answer (score 0):

There is no byte data type in Javascript.

Normally you use the `Number` data type to represent numbers like that.

```
var timestamp = [];
```

You don't specify a type for the array. You can put any data type you like in each item.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: with typed arrays it is possible to specify a byte data type in javascript.